# Returning empty collections in accordance with Effective Java

Tags: java, collections, effective-java

`Effective Java`, Item 43 states:

> return unmodifiable empty collections instead of `null`.

So far so good. Are there any guidelines, exactly what to return? Does this question even make sense? What I am thinking about is:

- Does it make a difference whether you return an emtpy `LinkedList<>` or `ArrayList<>(0)`?
- Does it make a difference whether you return an empty `HashMap<>` or `TreeMap<>`?
- etc.

Performance difference? Hardly.

Memory footprint? Maybe.

CPU footprint? Maybe.

Should these static returns be declared globally (i.e., cached)?

Comment: If you're returning single global instances, then you'd need to return immutable views.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're already cached for you by the `Collections` class, which contains some utility methods.

You can use `Collections.emptySet()`, `Collections.emptyMap()` and `Collections.emptyList()` that return immutable empty collections. Just as long as you're using the `Set`, `Map` and `List` interfaces in your code, as you should.

There are also methods for returning (again immutable) collections containing a single instance, such as `Collections.singletonList(mySingleElement)`.

They don't really affect performance, but they do make your code clearer:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>());
```

vs.

```
return Collections.emptyList();
```

You can also find `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` etc. but when using the methods you avoid getting warnings due to (lack of) generics.

Comment: worth mentioning that these are immutable? (and 'generics-friendly')

Comment: The example should be `Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>());`. Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you care about here: making sure that the returned collection is **immutable**.

And you get that when usingthe various `emptyXyz()` methods from the Collection class. In that sense: just make sure that you always use these methods; and don't waste time thinking about alternatives.

As in: don't start worrying about performance unless you do something in the order of millions of calls in a brief period of time. It is much more important that you write simple, clean, readable code. Because when you do that, you (most often) also have code that isn't dramatically "slow".

Meaning: of course, one should avoid outright stupid performance mistakes. But when that part is covered - don't *assume* you should worry about performance. Performance becomes an issue when *customers* complain. And then you **profile** what your code is doing, to find the true trouble makers. And if you then find `emptyList()` to be one thing that is more expensive than anything else and costing you too much - then come back and write up a question about that. (which will probably never happen)

Comment: @StephenC Sir yes sir. Added in.